# Jquery What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fa').hide();
   $('.icon').click (function(){
     $('.icon').addClass('active');
     if($(".fa").css("display") == "none") {
       $(".fa").show();
     }
     if $('.icon').click && $('.icon').hasCalss('active') (function(){
       $(".fa").hide();
     });
   });
});
```

I want it so that when you click on a div(in this case '.icon') The div .fa shows but when I click on it again and .fa is showing it hides .fa
In the console it keeps on coming up with these 2 errors

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   identifier

but I don't know whats wrong as i'm quite new to jquery and java-script.
Help would be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: `.hasCalss(` Spelling matters in programming, and `if $('.icon')` but `if` statements must be followed by `(`, etc

Comment: .hasCalss should be .hasClass

Comment: `$('.icon').hasClass('active')(function() { ... })` (using a boolean as a function that takes a function) is also... interesting. You should probably take a tutorial/course about JS, and then jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, hasClass is spelled wrong. I have fixed it in the code but it has changed nothing.  If you want to look at the protect follow this link. https://thimbleprojects.org/miniocto/591825

Comment: I'd suggest figuring out the basics of JS syntax before trying to get your head around the functions of any particular library

Answer (score 0):

You need to use toogle function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fa').hide();
   $('.icon').click (function(){
     $('.icon').addClass('active');
     $(".fa").toogle();
   });
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: An answer with a typo seems very appropriate here :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about switching classes on click you can use the `.toggleClass()`-method:
[Link to toggleClass() on http://api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). 
Just use your CSS-Class to manipulate the state.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  const icon =  $('.icon');
   
  icon.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });

   
 });
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #ddd;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon.active {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="container">

  <span class="icon active">
    <i class="fas fa-stroopwafel"></i>
  </span>
  
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i>
  </span>
  
</section>
```